# How to process a folder path with space and use conditional enconding?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to adapt this script:

```
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$Diretorio
)

Get-ChildItem $Diretorio\*  -recurse -Include *.srt,*.txt | ForEach-Object {
$content = $_ | Get-Content

Set-Content -PassThru $_.Fullname $content -Encoding UTF8 -Force}
```

It gets a folder path and then encodes all `.txt` or `.srt` to UTF-8.
It works nice, but it crashes when the folder path has a space like in `c://docs/movie joker`. It only works when the folder path doesn't have any space.

So, I need to make these two adjustments:

1. Process also folder paths with one or more spaces.
2. Conditionally encode to UTF-8 **IF** the file isn't already encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Can you show us how you're currently executing the script? I don't see any immediate issues with whitespace handling in paths in the script itself, so maybe it's just a question of you having to invoke `.\script.ps1 -Diretorio "C:\docs\movie joker"` instead of `.\script.ps1 -Diretorio C:\docs\movie joker`

Comment: Thanks for answering! So, the code is it all itself. Then I run it and it asks for the directory, I pass it and it encode every .srt and .txt to utf8. I tried your solution, but without the double quotes, it crashes with white spaces. With the double quotes though, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: _"encode to utf8 IF the file isn't already UTF8"_ depends if you want to test for UTF8 **with** BOM (Byte Order Mark). Most UTF8 files nowadays do not have a BOM.. To test if a file starts with the UTF8 BOM, you could do something like `$bom = $(foreach ($byte in (Get-Content -Path $file -Encoding byte -ReadCount 4 -TotalCount 4)) {'{0:x2}' -f $byte }) -join ''; if ($bom -match '^efbbbf') { <# file is UTF8 with BOM #> }`

Comment: Also, since you are using the `-Recurse` switch, leave out the `\*` you append to $Diretorio

Comment: Thanks for answering, @Theo. Actually, it doesn't matter if it is with BOM or not. I'm working on this script for encoding all txt files to UTF8 because my TV only reads in this format. But I need to encode conditionally because if the txt is already UTF8 with or without BOM, it encodes again, then some chars gets messy.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, as I debugged I've found that the problem is not the white spaces, is that my path has square brackets [] on it, and it crashes my script. Can you help me?

Comment: Use `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Diretorio`  (and similarly `-LiteralPath $_.FullName` with `Set-Content`)- `-LiteralPath` won't attempt wilcard expansion and will correctly pass paths with `[` in them

Comment: Thanks, I think we're on the way now. But now it returns me Unauthorized access...